# Как в href подставить value из тэга select

Tags: javascript, html

Всем привет, у меня есть select

```
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
        <select id="inputState" class="form-control select-css">
          <option selected disabled>Тип техники</option>
          <option>Красный</option>
          <option>Синий</option>
        </select>
      </div>
```

и

```
<a href="?filter[phone]=???"><img style="padding-right: 5px" src="/img/fonts/lupa.svg" alt="">Искать</a>
```

В ссылке вместо вопросительных знаков нужно поставить значение из выбранного select. Подскажите как это сделать, заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector('#inputState').onchange = function (evt) {
  let el = document.querySelector('a');
  el.href = '?filter[phone]='+evt.target.value;
  console.log(el);
};
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
  <select id="inputState" class="form-control select-css">
    <option selected disabled>Тип техники</option>
    <option>Красный</option>
    <option>Синий</option>
  </select>
</div>
<a href="?filter[phone]=???"><img style="padding-right: 5px" src="/img/fonts/lupa.svg" alt="">Искать</a>
```

Comment: Огромное огромное спасибо!